# How to return the list of nodes in a tree efficiently in c++

Tags: c++, list, tree, binary-tree, std

Here's a simplified version of my Node class :

```
class Node {
public:
    Node();

    // indicators of whether the node is a top or bottom node
    bool Top;
    bool Bot;

    // pointers for tree structure
    Node *Parent;
    Node *LeftC;
    Node *RightC;

    std::list<Node*> getNodesList();
};
```

What I want is be able to get a list of pointers to the nodes in my tree in a certain order. I tried the following code to do this :

```
std::list<Node*> Node::getNodesList(){
    if (Bot) return (std::list<Node*>(1,this));
    else {
        std::list<Node*> temp (1,this);
        temp.splice(temp.end(), LeftC->getNodesVector()); // Combine with left childrens
        temp.splice(temp.end(), RightC->getNodesVector()); // Combine with right childrens
        return temp;
    }
}
```

The splice function doesn't work and give me an error.

So my questions are :

- Why isn't the splice function working to combine the lists?
- Is there a more efficient way to return the list of pointers to the nodes?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want all them in a list?  It kind of defeats the point of a tree.  I would just keep track of the head node, from there you can access all elements in your tree

Comment: There are solid reasons for using trees and then wanting the results spliced in an array.  Heapsort is one I can think of.  I'm sure there are more.  No there is not a more efficient way, each node must be visited once.  O(N) is as good as you can do.

Comment: Note: you shouldn't need to keep track of "top" and "bot" a node is the bottom node when it doesn't have any children, and the top node is the only node with no parent.  Most trees don't even have a parent pointer.  You gain access back up the tree by returning up the recursive call stack, not by querying a node for its parent.

Answer (score 1):

Since I do not know the exact error you have, just a quick glance at your code tells me that your `Node` class probably doesn't know what `getNodesVector()` is since it isn't defined in your class.